# What does it mean for a function $f$ to be defined on a disk? (Clairaut's theorem)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, functions, definition

Clairaut's theorem states:

"Suppose $f$ is defined on a disk $D$ that contains the point $(a,b)$. If the functions..."

My question is just about the first part of this. What does it mean for a function to be defined on a disk?

Does it just mean that that disc (which is a always a subset and always(?) a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2 $) is the domain of the function in question? In that case, doesn't defining $f$ only make sense for a function of two variables and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means that $f$ must be defined at least on a disk (a filled in circle) centred at $(a, b)$. It may be defined elsewhere too. It doesn't really matter for the purposes of determining derivatives anyway; only points around $(a, b)$ will determine its various derivatives.

Comment: In the case of the OP, $(a,b)$ is only contained in $D$, it is not necessarily the center of it.

Comment: Given it didn't specify open disk, I decided to modify the condition slightly to one that was correct. :-)

Comment: Ahh okay, so it means $f$ successfully maps every point within that disk (and possibly other points as well) to a value (i.e. it isn't undefined)? In the event that those points on the disc are the only ones $f$ is defined for, is it correct to say that the disk is $f$'s domain? Also, doesn't defining $f$ in terms of this disc only make sense for a function of two variables?

Comment: Yes, if the function is *only* defined on the disk, then the disk is the function's domain. Otherwise, it's just (strictly) contained in the function's domain. The term "disk" is typically used primarily in two dimensions (for two variables). The more general term is "ball", and Clairaut's theorem does work for more variables.